# Cannot remove white border around bxSlider

Tags: javascript, css, border, bxslider

I am trying to get rid of the white border around a box slider. It displays a 5px white solid border. I tried border:0 !important in css and outline:0 in the js. I tried box-sizing:border-box. And i tried box-shadow:none.
The result is a 5px white border around bxSlider

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    width: auto;
    margin: 70px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #d8d2d2;
}

a.slide {
    width: 100%;
}

#bxSlider {
    background-color: #d8d2d2;
    border:0 !important;
}
```

JS

```
`$('.bxSlider').bxSlider({
    mode: 'vertical',
  speed: 500,
  nextSelector: '#slider-next',
  prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
  nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right" style="color:black; font-size:42px"/> </i>',  
  prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left" style="color:black; font-size:42px"/> &nbsp; </i>',    
  slideMargin: 0,
  infiniteLoop: true,
  pager: false,
  outline: 0,  
  minSlides: 3,
  maxSlides:3,
  moveSlides: 3,
  adaptiveHeight: false,
  slideSelector: 'a.slide'
});`
```

Comment: It's obviously not coming from the code you posted. Have you used the browser inspector to track it down?

Comment: `.bx-wrapper {border: 5px solid #fff;}`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
.bx-wrapper {
    border:0 !important;
}
```

Cause it looks like the border is applied on the wrapper and not on the slidder

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a parent class to the `#bxSlider` element and use that in your CSS:

```
    #wrapper {
      /* existing code */
    }
    .slider-container #bxSlider {
      border: 0 !important;
}
```